# Creating a UDP Connection on Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

I'm trying to create a simple UDP connection on a given port with Android Studio and their emulator. I was able to make this work with a client/server both running in threads with eclipse.

However, when porting the code into android the port that is opened is TCP.

Below is the android code:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        // Perform our network ops in this loop, anything blocking really...

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "UDP Connecting to " + HOST + " on port " + PORT);
            datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();

            String host = "localhost";
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);

            byte[] message = "UDP is da best".getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, address, PORT);

            datagramSocket.send(packet);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
            DatagramPacket incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

            while (true) {
                datagramSocket.receive(incoming);
                byte[] data = incoming.getData();
                String s = new String(data, 0, incoming.getLength());

                Log.d(TAG, "Client: " + incoming.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " : " + incoming.getPort() + " - " + s);

                Thread.sleep(500);

                DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(s.getBytes() , s.getBytes().length , incoming.getAddress() , PORT);
                datagramSocket.send(dp);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }

    }
```

This code is pretty much taken from [here](http://www.binarytides.com/udp-socket-programming-in-java/)

Here is a picture of the ports being created as TCP:

[image]

Comment: I figured out port 5555 is already in use by android, so i've moved to 9876 with still no results

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved with first changing ports as 5555 is in use and 127.0.0.1 is not the ip to use either, using 10.0.2.2 let me connect and everything worked out